# Is there a way to load hidden divs within a div before their parent using AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have a `dropdown` menu which shows/hides `divs` on a page based on the selection. I am also passing parameters from links on a prior page to pre-select the dropdown choice. Unfortunately when the dropdown is pre-selected, the hidden div does not load. This seems to be the order in which the divs appear in the code and thus, on page load.

I have read that loading a div last on a page is possible using `AJAX`... but I have not found loading a child before a parent being addressed. I have a feeling this is because it is not possible, but figured I'd ask! You can look at code below:

Current JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('donationdropdown').addEventListener('change', function() {
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.paymentinfo'), function(e) {
            e.style.display = 'none';
        });
        var sel = +this.selectedIndex - 1;
        if (sel >= 0) {
            document.getElementById('payMethod').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('pay' + sel).style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            document.getElementById('payMethod').style.display = 'none';
        }
    });
</script>
```

Current HTML:

```
<div id="d">

  <select class="cat_donationdropdown" id="donationdropdown" name="donationdropdown">
    <option value="0">
      Select Donation Type Below
    </option>
    <option value="1" 
    <?php echo ($_GET['donationdropdown'] == '1' ? 'selected="selected"' : ''); ?>
      >1
    </option>
    <option value="2">
      2
    </option>
    <option value="3">
      3
    </option>
    <option value="4">
      4
    </option>
    <option value="5">
      5
    </option>
  </select>
</div>
<div id="payMethod">

  <div id="payOptions">
    <div id="payInfo">
      <div id="pay0" class="paymentinfo indented">
        <?php
        $block = module_invoke('webform', 'block_view', 'client-block-57');
        print render($block['content']);
        ?>
      </div>
      <div id="pay1" class="paymentinfo indented">
        <?php
        $block = module_invoke('webform', 'block_view', 'client-block-58');
        print render($block['content']);
        ?>
      </div>
      <div id="pay2" class="paymentinfo indented">
        <?php
        $block = module_invoke('webform', 'block_view', 'client-block-58');
        print render($block['content']);
        ?>
      </div>
      <div id="pay3" class="paymentinfo indented">
        <?php
        $block = module_invoke('webform', 'block_view', 'client-block-57');
        print render($block['content']);
        ?>
      </div>
      <div id="pay4" class="paymentinfo indented">
        <?php
        $block = module_invoke('webform', 'block_view', 'client-block-57');
        print render($block['content']);
        ?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow, I think you're making this all far too complicated. You tagged this with jQuery, so here's a jQuery solution:

Try setting all the `.paymentinfo` elements to hidden by default using CSS, then use a `$(document).ready()` to fire the show/hide function based on the selectbox value. After that, when you change the selectbox, it just fires the show/hide function again.

[Working JSFiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/Lzmp0632/)

```
<style>
    .paymentinfo{
        display:none;
    }
</style>

$(document).ready(function(){
 showHide($("#donationdropdown").val());
});

$('#donationdropdown').on('change', function() {
  showHide($(this).val());
});

function showHide(id){
    $(".paymentinfo").hide();
    $("#pay" + id).show();
}
```

Comment: That script is less complicated, but the issue is my blocks will not render if they are pre-selected. The only way to pre-select from dropdown box based off link on previous page using a GET method is to have content of children of a div load before their parent.

Comment: Why won't they render? You're doing all that before the page loads with PHP, right? They shouldn't care what happens after the page loads.